# Integral closure of integrally closed ring in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to prove:

> If $B$ is integral closure of $A$ in some field extnesion $L$ of the quotient field of $A$, then $S^{-1}B$ is the integral closure of $S^{-1}A$ in $L$.

I could prove:

> (a) Let $A$ be a subring of a ring $B$, integral over $A$. Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$. Then $S^{-1}B$ is integral over $S^{-1}A$. If $A$ is integrally closed, then $S^{-1}A$ is integrally closed.
>
> (b) Integral closure of $A$ in some field extension $L$ is integrally closed.

I am thinking to complete the problem as follows:

> *$S^{-1}B$ is integrally closed and integral over $S^{-1}A$ **hence** $S^{-1}B$ is integral closure of $S^{-1}A$ in $L$.*

Problem is: if $C$ is integrally closed $C \subseteq L$ for some field, then the integral closure of $C$ in $L$ is $C$ (?)

Comment: What do you mean by integrally closed? Do you mean this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed

Comment: My definition for $C$ being integrally closed is that it is closed in its field of fractions $Quot(C)$. If $C \subseteq L$ where $L$ is a field, then we embed $Quot(C)$ into $L$.

Comment: Using your definition, let $C=\mathbb{Z}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$. Then $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed in $\mathbb{Q}$, but the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right.